# SQL query to return first word after -

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring

I have a field where I need to pull the first word after "- " character
example: Input= `853 - RACEWAY SALES`. Output = `RACEWAY`

I am using:

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
     WHEN [Warehouse name] LIKE '853 - RACEWAY SALES' 
        THEN SUBSTRING(
                [Warehouse name], 
                CHARINDEX('-', [Warehouse name]), 
                CHARINDEX('', [Warehouse name]) - CHARINDEX('-', [Warehouse name]) + Len('')
             ) 
   END AS A
```

This is throwing me an error.

Comment: What do you define as a "word"? If you have the value `123 - Steve. John` would you expect `Steve.` or `Steve`? What about `456 - Jane-Sally`? What about `789 - Kev&Pauline`? What about `147 - Jumbo9 Tiny5`?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Please provide more sample data and desired results to cover all edge cases

Comment: The field will always be in the format of 123 - Steve John

Comment: Error is Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: This is not the way you should handle, but the error you are getting is caused by `len('')` part. if you change to `Len([Warehouse name])` you won't get the error.

Comment: This is giving me out as - Raceway sales. But I need to pull only Raceway

Comment: You may want to apply wild card %% to your case... Otherwise you are only looking for that particular string

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer is :

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT '853 - RACEWAY SALES'  AS STRING
)
SELECT LEFT(RIGHT(STRING, LEN(STRING) - CHARINDEX('-', STRING) - 1), CHARINDEX(' ', RIGHT(STRING, LEN(STRING) - CHARINDEX('-', STRING) - 1)) - 1)
FROM T
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try

```
SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(
                '853 - RACEWAY SALES' , 
                CHARINDEX('-', '853 - RACEWAY SALES' )+1
                ,CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE('853 - RACEWAY SALES' ))+2
             )
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
select PARSENAME(REPLACE( PARSENAME(REPLACE('853 - RACEWAY SALES', '-', '.'), 1) , ' ' ,'.'),2)
```